# How to fill in date in puppeteer js

Tags: puppeteer

I have the following on a form:

```html
<input
  type="date"
  placeholder="Date of Birth"
  name="11171977"
  data-componentname="dateOfBirth"
  autocomplete="off"
  autocorrect="off"
  autocapitalize="off"
  spellcheck="false"
  data-ddlabel="dd"
  data-mmlabel="mm"
  data-yyyylabel="yyyy"
/>
```

On all other elements I can select like this:

```js
document.querySelector('[data-componentname="dateOfBirth"]').value = '1119189';
```

However on the date it doesn't work.  How would I fill this out?

Comment: you should check if it has `readOnly` attribute , if it has you should use `page.evaluate` to remove attribute & then type in.
```
 await page.focus("[name='j_idt31:verisysForm:issuedate_input']");
  await page.$eval("[name='j_idt31:verisysForm:issuedate_input']", (e) =>
    e.removeAttribute("readonly")
  );
  await page.type("[name='j_idt31:verisysForm:issuedate_input']", "17-07-2018");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `value` for `date` input reqires some format like `"yyyy-MM-dd"`. You can also use `.valueAsDate` property with `Date` objects.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing it like this:

```
await page.focus('[data-componentname="dateOfBirth"]');
await page.keyboard.type('11171977');
```

Comment: Similarly, `page.type('[data-componentname="dateOfBirth"]', '11171977')` is worth trying too.