# "type" value into input date field with puppeteer

Tags: html, input, puppeteer, accessibility

I'm trying to simulate with puppeteer a user entering a value into an input date field (eg `<input type="date" />`), but I'm experiencing different behaviour than when a human actually does this. I'm not sure if this is a bug in Puppeteer or if I'm doing something wrong.

Everywhere I've found saying how to enter the value suggests merely `page.keyboard.type(selector, value)`, but when I do that, nothing gets entered (but it looks like it's trying):

(animated GIF, cuz SO won't let me add the video. beware the GIF is real annoying)

> [image: 1]

Alternatively, I tried first selecting the field, and then using `elementHandle.type(value)`, which at least does *something*, but the value entered is jumbled nonsense:

(animated GIF, cuz SO won't let me add the video. beware the GIF is real annoying)

> [image: 2]

One strange thing is that when Puppeteer focuses the field (via Tab key), `yyyy` is selected; but when I human does it, `dd` is selected.

I also tried slicing the value up and manually setting each "piece", but that results in the same behaviour as `elementHandle.type(value)`.

Also frustrating, it seems to be impossible to determine what piece of the input date is focused (ex `document` and `window` `.getSelection().toString()` is empty).

Comment: I’m sorry but what is the question here? Are you looking for a workaround to at least test something? Otherwise, your question simply states the presence of a bug in puppeteer, it would seem. I guess you should [file a bug report on their Github page](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues), you’d get better insights into the causes from the developers.

Comment: A complete, runnable [mcve] would be nice.

Comment: Related: [How to fill in date in puppeteer js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62331161/how-to-fill-in-date-in-puppeteer-js)

Comment: @Andy, i'm not sure it is a bug. i was hoping to confirm that before bothering them.

Comment: i'll work on a repro on the airplane this evening

Comment: @ggorlen, thanks i saw that. however, as i mentioned "I'm trying to simulate with puppeteer a user entering a value into an input date field". a user would not manually set the DOM `value` attribute. also, that does not work with react (the value is immediately discarded/reset—I tried already as a worst-case fallback; i was not able to find any way to trick react into accepting the DOM mutation, such as firing a change event on the node after changing the value).

Comment: The linked thread has [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62331516/6243352) that doesn't use `value`: `page.type()` and `page.keyboard`, which give trusted events as a user would. These worked for me on the input you showed, so I'm unable to reproduce your problem. React was not mentioned in your post, so I'd have to see a sample component or the actual page to be able to help with whatever different behavor it might have versus a native HTML5 date input. Also, even if it doesn't wind up being a dupe, it's still useful for context and future visitors who wind up here from a search.

Comment: The problem is caused if the picker is ever opened. as long as the picker is not opened at all, the issue does not occur.